# iOS: OpenGL ES2 incorrect vertex rendering order

Tags: ios, opengl-es-2.0, render, vertex

I'm rendering a 3D object in OpenGL ES2 on iPhone, the model is loaded from a .obj file. Previously the render engine was implemented in ES1 and I was using the same structure, same element buffer, and everything was ok. 
Now I want to migrate to ES2, but when I draw the model, it seems that the vertices are drawn in a different order, but the array buffer and element array buffer is the same. 
Here is my vertex structure:

```
struct Vertex
{
    union { struct { float x, y, z; }; float position[3]; };
    union { struct { float nx, ny, nz; }; float normal[3]; };
    union { struct { float u, v; }; float uv0[2]; };
};
```

My vertex shader is correct, because I rendered a cube, and everything was fine. 
Here is a screenshot of the result, rendered with ES2:

[image]

Comment: Does it always look like that (from frame to frame and run to run), or do the vertices jump around all over the place?

Comment: Yes, it always looks like this.

Comment: My first guess would be something wrong with the vertex index data you're using. Otherwise something wrong with the vertex data. Can you post your code which sets up the vertex attributes (`glVertexAttribPointer`)?

Comment: I use the same vertex and index buffer as in ES1. Here is the code: glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, (*glBuffers).first);
    
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, (*glBuffers).second);
   
    glVertexAttribPointer(positionSlot_, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE,
                          sizeof(Geometry::Vertex), 0); GLsizei model_size = model->resource_manager()->zero_model()->getIndices().size();
    
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES,
                   model_size,
                   GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,
                   0);

Comment: Are you using the result of `glGetAttribLocation` for `positionSlot`? A common mistake (i.e. one that I've made) is to use the same value as you would pass to `glGetActiveAttrib`.

Comment: Yes, I'm using glGetAttribLocation.
positionSlot_ = glGetAttribLocation(programHandle, "Position");
    normalSlot_ = glGetAttribLocation(programHandle, "Normal");texCoordSlot_ = glGetAttribLocation(programHandle, "TexCoordIn");
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(texCoordSlot_);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(positionSlot_);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(normalSlot_);